# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'credentials' of 'this.props' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

Username prop coming up as undefined. It shows in state under credentials under currentUser so I'm not sure why this is happening. Error shown in:

```
const {
   classes,
   currentUser: {
     credentials: { username, image },
     loading,
     authenticated,
   },
  } = this.props;
```

Full code:

```
class messages extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedChat: null,
      newChatFormVisible: false,
      chats: [],
    };
  }

  selectChat = (chatIndex) => {
    ...};

  newChatBtnClicked = () => {
    ...};

  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      currentUser: {
        credentials: { username, image },
        loading,
        authenticated,
      },
    } = this.props;

    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("chats")
      .where("users", "array-contains", username)
      .onSnapshot(async (res) => {
        const chats = res.docs.map((_doc) => _doc.data());
        await this.setState({
          chats: chats,
        });
        console.log(this.state);
      });

    let messagesMarkup = !loading ? (
      authenticated ? (
        <div>
          <div>Open Messages</div>
          <ChatList
            history={this.props.history}
            newChatBtn={this.newChatBtnClicked}
            selectChat={this.selectedChat}
            username={username}
            selectedChatIndex={this.state.selectedChat}
          ></ChatList>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    ) : (
      <p> loading...</p>
    );
    return messagesMarkup;
  }
}

messages.propTypes = {
  currentUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  credentials: state.currentUser.credentials,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(messages);
```

I've tried credentials.username with no luck. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something with the mapStateToProps? I want to get the currentUser so I can display all of their chat messages and their username is under credentials, under currentUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`credentials` happens to be `undefined` so js cannot destructure

You could:

a- Set their default values this way:

```
    const {
      classes,
      currentUser: {
        credentials: { username, image } = { username: 'foo', image: 'bar' },
        loading,
        authenticated,
      },
    } = this.props;
```

b- Pass each `currentUser` properties as props by destructuring the object upstream with `<messages {...currentUser}>` and set their default values using `messages.defaultProps = { credentials: { username: 'foo', image: 'bar' }}` or adding `defaultProps` class attribute where you define the component. This could be seen as more idiomatic

c- Make sure `credentials` is never `undefined` when using the component ^^